# How would I increment a color value on MouseOver trigger in XAML template?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hi all,

I am working on creating a button template to use in my WPF application. The format is basically color tiles (Think Windows Phone style for the most part.).

If I was wanting to change the color of the button in the event of a MouseOver, I would just make some code like this (let's say the original button color is Gray):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColorTileButton" TargetType="Button>

<!-- Insert various property editing here. -->

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

But obviously this wouldn't work if the original button color was, say, Firebrick because I would end up with a bunch of standard Gray buttons. So I was wondering if there would be a way to rewrite this button template so that it would just increment the values of R, G, and B by about 10 to give the button a lighter color, then decrement is when the mouse left. Help me out?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are describing is [ColorAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation.aspx) an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753266.aspx), or you can look at this [Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2d7cccd7-ffeb-4fb3-81e3-fe311ae8ef7c/). An interesting note from the Forum post.

> A trigger makes a change to one or more properties when its condition is satisfied, and then resets the property values when its condition is no longer satisfied.

So what he is suggesting is:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" /> 
    </Trigger> 
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

it would reset to FireBrick as you gave in your example

Comment: Well, this is a lot simpler than I thought it was going to be. I'm used to having to code a way for the control to revert to its original color, so this has been a pleasant surprise for me. Didn't know that XAML made this convenient for you. Thanks!